# Passing a SparkR dataframe into a user-defined function

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I know that to apply a user-defined function to a SparkR dataframe, one can use dapply/gapply. I wonder if it's a good practice to pass a SparkR dataframe directly into a UDF? e.g., first create a dataframe

```
df <- createDataFrame(mtcars)
```

then pass the dataframe into a UDF for some transformations

```
myFunction <- function(df) {
  return( df$mpg * 2)
}

df$new_col <- myFunction(df)
```

I tried the above code and it worked. But I'm just not sure if this is recommended.

If passing a dataframe is OK, additionally, can I pass in the column as an argument? e.g.

```
myFunction <- function(colName) {
  return( colName * 2 )
}
df$new_col <- myFunction(df$mpg)
```

Thank you.